# Outlook VBA ReceivedTime "Invalid Qualifier"

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write an Outlook macro that takes a specific message (the "Selection" message as seen in the macro below) and save the message's attachment in a folder based on its ReceivedTime property. The intent is to eventually expand the macro to open the attachment in Excel and run an already-written Excel macro on it, but I'm trying to start small.

However, whenever I try to run the macro below, it says the ReceivedTime property is an "invalid qualifier". I've never even seen this error before and have no idea what it means or what to do.

```
Sub DailyPinkOL()
    Call initMonths
    Dim inbox As Folder
    Dim att As Attachment
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    Dim mi As MailItem
    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlat As Excel.Workbook
    Set inbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    If Selection.Location <> olViewList Then Exit Sub
    Set mi = Selection
    Set att = mi.Attachments(1)
    att.SaveAsFile Path:="path1\Current Year\" & months(mi.ReceivedTime.Month) & "\" & mi.ReceivedTime.Month & "-" & mi.ReceivedTime.Day & ".xlsx"
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("path2\file1")
End Sub
```

path1, path2, and file1 are replaced by actual file paths and files in the actual macro; I copied it this way for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
att.SaveAsFile Path:="path1\Current Year\" & months(mi.ReceivedTime.Month) & "\" & mi.ReceivedTime.Month & "-" & mi.ReceivedTime.Day & ".xlsx"
```

has two errors as far as I see:

mi.ReceivedTime.Month does not exist; go for Month(mi.ReceivedTime) instead.

mi.ReceivedTime.Day does not exist; go for Day(mi.ReceivedTime) instead

so it should be:

```
att.SaveAsFile Path:="path1\Current Year\" & month(mi.ReceivedTime) & "\" & month(mi.ReceivedTime) & "-" & day(mi.ReceivedTime) & ".xlsx"
```

you are also having other code I do not unterstand (and my Outlook throws Errors) like
    If Selection.Location <> olViewList Then Exit Sub
    Call initMonths
but if they work for you everything is fine....

Max